# Plane Detection for L-shaped surfaces In Unity using ARKit

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to use ARKit in unity to do plane detection with an IPhone. The goal is to use this in a classroom and identify the surfaces of the tables. I set up everything in unity and wrote a script to exclude the floor from the plane detection, since I'm only interested in the tables. The plane detection works fine for individual rows of tables in the room and detects those as individual surfaces.

The problem now is that some classrooms have the tables organised in an L-shape or a U-shape. which means theres basically a column and a row of tables connected to each-other. This causes the App to recognise the tables not as a separate row and a column, but instead draws a huge plane from the corner of the row to the other corner of the column, which leads to a huge plane spanning a rectangle. This means i have a plane that does cover the tables, but also a huge are, where there isn't actually supposed to be a plane.

I need the plane to only follow where the table surfaces are and not fill out a square from edge to edge.

I tried a lot of stuff, like setting a max width and max length value for the planes, and basically reducing the plane, if it would go over that value. But setting the plane.size doesn't change anything and I tried a lot of different stuff so far, that I can't remember all of it anymore. I don't know how I can approach this problem. Any suggestion is welcomed.

My current Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

public class ElevatedSurfaceDetector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ARPlaneManager arPlaneManager;
    private float minHeight = 1.2f; // Adjust this value based on your

    private float tableWidth = 0.8f;
    private float tableLength = 1.6f;
    private ARPlane boundedPlane;

    void Update()
    {
        foreach (var plane in arPlaneManager.trackables)
        {
            IsElevatedSurface(plane);
            PlaneBoundaryConstraint(plane);
            Debug.Log("Planes Count: " + arPlaneManager.trackables.count);
        }
    }

    /*private void DetectElevatedSurfaces()
    {
        foreach (var plane in arPlaneManager.trackables)
        { 
            // Check if the plane is not already in the list and is above the minHeight
            if (!IsElevatedSurface(plane) && plane.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                // Your additional logic for handling the new elevated plane can go here
                //plane.gameObject.SetActive(false);

                Debug.Log("PLANE DISABLED");
            }
        }
    }*/

    private bool IsElevatedSurface(ARPlane plane)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Plane Height: "+plane.gameObject.transform.position.y + "\nCamera Height: "+GetComponentInParent<ARSessionOrigin>().Camera.gameObject.transform.position.y);

        float heightDif = Math.Abs(GetComponentInParent<ARSessionOrigin>().Camera.gameObject.transform.position.y - plane.gameObject.transform.position.y);

        plane.gameObject.SetActive(heightDif <= minHeight);

        return heightDif <= minHeight;
        // Check if the plane is not the floor and is above the minHeight
        //return plane.center.y > minHeight;
    }

    private void PlaneBoundaryConstraint(ARPlane plane)
    {

        if (plane.isActiveAndEnabled)
        {
            if (plane.size.y > tableWidth)
            {
                Debug.Log("Max Width: " + plane.size.y);

                plane.size.Set(tableWidth, tableLength);
                //GameObject newPlane = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
                //newPlane.GetComponent<Plane>().SetNormalAndPosition(plane.normal, plane.center);
                //newPlane.transform.localScale = new(tableLength / 10, 1, tableWidth / 10);
                //newPlane.transform.position = new(plane.transform.position.x, plane.transform.position.y, plane.transform.position.z);
                //newPlane.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(plane.transform.rotation.x, plane.transform.rotation.y,plane.transform.rotation.z, plane.transform.rotation.w);
                //plane.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                Debug.Log(plane.gameObject.transform.localScale.ToString());
            }

            else if (plane.size.x > tableLength)
            {
                plane.size.Set(tableWidth, tableLength);
                //plane.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                Debug.Log("Max Length: " + plane.size.x);
                //plane.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }

        }
    }
}
```